# How to stop a program if file doesn't exist in a folder using java?

Tags: java, file, exit

i have a program which select recent files from a directory and compress them into one file.
but i want to stop the program if there is no files in the directory and display an error message like "There is no files in the deirectory"

I tried append this:

if(file.exists)
{   }
else
{   }

but i don't know how to insert it inside my code.

Thank you

```
{
    String source = "C:/Source";
    String target = "C:/Target";

    File sourceDir = new File(source);
    File[] files = sourceDir.listFiles();

    if(files.exists())

    Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>()
    {
        public int compare(File f1, File f2)
        {
            return (int) (f2.lastModified() - f1.lastModified());
        }
    });

    // create the target directory
    File targetDir = new File(target);
    targetDir.mkdirs();

{  
    for(int i=0, length=Math.min(files.length, 12); i<length; i++)
        files[i].renameTo(new File(targetDir, files[i].getName()));


     PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:/Joined/joined.txt"));
    File file = new File("C:/Target");

    File[] files2 = file.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < files2.length; i++)
    {

      File currentFile = files2[i];

      System.out.println("Processing " + currentFile.getPath() + "... ");

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(currentFile));

      String line = br.readLine();

      while (line != null)
      {
        pw.println(line);
        line = br.readLine();
      }
      br.close();
    }
    pw.close();

 Thread.sleep(2000);
try
{
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("c:\\Joined\\Join.bat");
   Process p = pb.start();

}
catch (IOException e)
 {
e.printStackTrace();
}
    }}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using System.exit() method it is better to use guard clauses to prevent further execution. Using System.exit() is not a good practice as it halts the flow abruptly. Ideal solution would be

```
if (file.exists()) 
   return; //Use appropriate returns according to the method signature.

// Block of code that does something with the file.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to call method exit like this:

```
System.exit(0);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Adding System.exit(0) is not advised. A program must be terminated only through the natural flow.

Answer (score 1):

If `sourceDir` does not refer to a directory, you'll get `null` from `listFiles`, so that's a first thing you could check.

If it indeed refers to a directory, and the directory is empty, you'll simply get an empty array back from `listFiles`. So you could use

```
if (files.length() == 0) {
    System.err.println("There is no files in the deirectory");
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: Right where you now have `if(files.exists())`

Answer (score 0):

After

```
File[] files2 = file.listFiles();
```

you can do

```
if(files2.length == 0)
{
    System.err.println("Error - no files found!");
```

and if you want the program to completely close,

```
    System.exit(1); //0 denotes normal close, 1 denotes an error
}
```

and if you want the program to continue to the next step,

```
    break; //exit the current loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the `if(files.exists())`, make sure to include brackets (`{` and `}`) with all that chunk of code you just mentioned

For example:

```
if(files.exists()) {
    // code you want it to run if files exist
} else System.err.println("No Files Exist In This Directory...")
```